# Magento 2 Admin - Base table or view not found

Tags: database, category-products, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.3, join-table

I have 5 different domains for a Magento 2 installation - 4 websites and 1 admin side.
I got a spontaneous exception when I'm trying to get access to an admin login form by admin URL(it was ok before, without errors):

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.catalog_category_product_index_store0' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT DISTINCT  COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
> INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
> INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=0 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=0
> INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (((e.visibility = '2') OR (e.visibility = '4'))) AND (((IFNULL(`e`.`sku`, 0) = 'VIOLON -0100, VENEZIA_D-0201, STELLAIRE-0100, SARAH-0100, MAGIK-0100, MACUMBA-0101, DANIELA-0600, VENDEE-0600, VIVIANE-0100, TOTIE-0201') )) AND (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)

But! A Store with id 0 is admin side... Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission issue, log in to the M2 admin portal and click on system->userRoles and check the role scope permission to your user, if it is custom then change this to all. Then it will work fine with all* in the URL.

Note: If you’re an existing customer migrating the Magento 2 instance from the previous Magento 2 edition, the category flow will not cause any error.